# A clickable <li> using an <a> tag - no JS to be used. Is it legal HTML?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have read a lot of times that inline elements should never contain block elements. I agree, there are problems with that and it can get messy after. But I find it the only solution to do the following:

I'm trying to create an HTML template that imitates the Metro UI "tiles" (yeah, the one that is in windows 8). The tiles are made using `<li>` elements. Now, the problem is that I want the tiles (the whole `<li>` tag) clickable, but proper HTML tells me you can't surround a block element with an inline element. Besides, you can't surround an `<li>` with an `<a>`. Is there any method of doing this without going against the rules of html?

Comment: do you mind sharing the code ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A legal and clean way of accomplishing this is to use a style of `inline-block` for the `A` tags and let them fill the complete `LI`.

```
LI > A
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

OR

```
LI > A
{
    display: block;
}
```

This will work in IE7+, and all recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.

Note that in the current *draft* of HTML 5, it is legal to put a greater variety of elements inside an anchor tag than was previously allowed (see "permitted content" and examples): http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html

Additional article: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: it it legal to place block elements in the <a> tag if i do it this way? <a> is an inline element.

Comment: @fskreuz - see my updated answer. In a word, yes, it is legal in HTML 5. Test carefully in older browsers.

Comment: seeing that it is legal in HTML5. Any suggestions for older browsers?

Comment: @fskreuz - I've used block content inside an anchor in IE7 and IE8 with no problem. However, I have noticed issues using the HTML 5 doctype in IE7. I would suggest trying it out, and opening another question with your specific code if you run into problems.

Comment: it works! although validation will disallow (i'm using xhtml strict). im not using the `>` for IE6 compatibility and instead, im using classes. to finish up, the `<a>` should have the `overflow:hidden` fix to fill up the whole container.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the stackoverflow menu you will see it is quite easy. You put a `<a>` inside a `<li>`, put it to display block and give it the padding you want to achieve the block feel.

Comment: the difference with stack's menu is that it only contains text which is in an `<a>` in an `<li>` which is perfectly legal. however, in my case, the `<a>` will not only contain text. it could contain paragraphs for example, which is a block element. still, block in inline scenario.