# <a> tag around <li> tag

Tags: html

I always want to ask this question:

Is this validate

```
<a><li></li></a>
```

Or should always have

```
<li><a></a></li>
```

Is the first way wrong or you are allow to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the first one is wrong, as only `<li>` is to be a child of a list. the second is correct.

by what i understand, you want the whole list item to be "clickable". putting everything in `<a>` is also viable - block AND inline elements. this is perfectly valid in HTML5. won't validate in older HTML though. however, it does act correctly, given that `<a>` is given the style of `display:block`

[A clickable <li> using an <a> tag - no JS to be used. Is it legal HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236522/575527)

Answer (score 2):

The first choice is incorrect. Second choice is correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to w3.org, only li tags are allowed in a ul or ol:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2