# when i right click mouse not show the open in new tab menu

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a problem, when i try to click a div it cannot redirect.

```
<div class="blockquote-box  blockquote-success clearfix">

<div class="square pull-left ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <img class="Width_40" src="Allbill.png" alt="">
    <span class="fa fa-heart fav-link FontSize-18" title="" data-original-title="Add to My Favorites"></span>
</div>
<a href="/customer/customerbilldetails">
    <h4>
        Bill Listing
    </h4>

    <p>
        Report listing bill details.
    </p>
</a>
```

I am using a tag. Inside the tag having the all elements,
[image]

when i right click mouse not show the open in new tab menu...
how can i resolve this ...please anyone help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Open New Tab" an other similar options only appear for links (`<a>`). You must place everything in an `<a>`. Technically, it will break the "No block elements inside inline elements" rule. However, you can style `<a>` to have `display:block` so it acts like a `<div>`.

A similar situation here: [A clickable <li> using an <a> tag - no JS to be used. Is it legal HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236522/575527)

Comment: This answer is misleading. HTML5 allows for this. "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)" http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Scroll click is working but right click the mouse and click new tab  is not available..