# Right click on Collapsed Menu Item of Ant Design do not show "Open in new tab"

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, antd, right-click

I have a React App that use Ant Design. It uses the Ant Design Menu component, in collapsed mode.

The thing is when I try to right click on a menu item, it do not show the options to "Open in new tab/window".

I suspect that it has relation with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683316/when-i-right-click-mouse-not-show-the-open-in-new-tab-menu), because when I use the code inspector, the collapsed menu item of Ant Design don't use `a` tags directly.

How can I achieve that the "Open in new tab/window" options of right click appears when I click on collapsed menu items of Ant Design???

**EDIT**

The code I have is pretty like this:

```
<Menu.Item
    key="menu_1"
    onClick={() => {
        window.location.href = '../path/to/route';
    }}
>
    Dashboard
</Menu.Item>
```

But my application has more than 30 menu items, so putting an `a` tag on each item is a solution that require many text. I want to apply a dynamic solution in execution time for this issue.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, Ant Design has this behavior because the structure of its item menu in collapse mode. It do not trigger a console error/warning. I thing the solution should be tricky code, not a fix of error/warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) wherever you want. Like in [Collapsed inline menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/#components-menu-demo-inline-collapsed), you can use as follows:

```
<Menu.Item key="3">
    <Icon type="inbox" />
    <span>
        <a href="#">Option 3</a>
    </span>
</Menu.Item>
```

I have created a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/18vyjon0r4), please check.

Comment: This was the solution that I applied to the code, but I was looking for a dynamic solution. Please, look update of the question.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez OK. Then, there should be some other solution.