# Running Javascript via href

Tags: javascript, html

```
<ul>
    <a href="#Project">
        <li onclick="project()">Projects</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

a tab appears and you can click on it, which runs a javascript function and also changes the url to www.demo.com#Project.

Is it possible when i give someone the link like `www.demo.com#Project` it loads the page and automatically runs `function project()`

**EDIT** *SOLUTION*

```
if(window.location.hash == "#Project") {
        setTimeout('project();', 1);
} 
else {
}
```

a timeout must be set so it loads the page first then execute function

Comment: You cannot have `<li>` directly as a child of `<a>` and also you cannot put `<li>` or any other block elements inside `<a>`. It's like putting a **bottle inside water, as a container**.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I fixed up the example code

Comment: Still the same. Read my comment correctly.

Comment: You can do this `<li><a></a></li>` but not `<a><li></li></a>`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236522/a-clickable-li-using-an-a-tag-no-js-to-be-used-is-it-legal-html)

Comment: Are you going to have multiple links like this, with an anchor and a corresponding JS function?

Comment: @Shaggy yes I have multiple links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, script won't run if your give someone the URL. To achive this you should check whether `window.location.hash` equals `'#Project'` on page load.

Hope this helps

Btw. what Praveen Kumar mentioned is changing your code as follow:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="project()">
        <a href="#Project">Projects</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want this to work on several different anchors, so you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="project()">
        <a href="#Project">Projects</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    function project() {
        alert('Function project called')
    };

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']")
    if (elements.length > 0)
    {
        elements[0].click();
    };
</script>
```

This code will make sure any hash anchor gets clicked when you navigate to the url with that hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
the link will be for example "www.test.com#myproject" 
and "function project" will be run automatically

 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    function project()
    {
      alert("hello");
    }    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="myproject">
        <img src="test.jpg" onload="project()">
      <a>  sample text</a>
        <p>123456789</p>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A small example

```
If (window.location.hash === '#Project')  {
  project() ;
}
```

Comment: doesnt work also why have you done `===` shouldn't it be  `==`

Comment: `if(window.location.hash == "#Project") {
        setTimeout('project();', 1);
        
    } else {
        // No hash
    }`

Is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You dont have to do `<a href="#Project">
        <li onclick="project()">Projects</li>
    </a>` because it is a painful code. Try to do this:

```
  `<ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="project()">Projects</a>
      </li>
  </ul>`
```

It basically run the function called `project()` when you click the **Projects**. Base on your code your just navigating an element that has an `id` of `Project`.

You can also use

```
<ul>
      <li>
          <a href="www.demo.com/projects.html">Projects</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

**Then in projects.html** run your script:

```
<script>

function project(){
  alert("I am your function.");
}

project(); //Call the function

</script>
```

Comment: but I dont want my website to have multiple pages.

Comment: `<ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#Projects" onclick="project()">Projects</a>
      </li>
  </ul>`

Comment: Try that one. Then let me know whats going on

Comment: The Same thing as i quoted. runs the function and make the url contain #Projects

Comment: No sir. Its not the same. Try to check your **HTML** structure. You must also consider the structure when developing.